# Adding a New Click Handler To An Existing Element?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to add a new click handler to the #myDiv element below. I've tried something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click", blah);

function blah() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

But I keep getting a console error stating, "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). Is this because the other event listener isn't being called yet? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        [data-color="red"] { color: red; }
        [data-color="blue"] { color: blue; }
        [data-color="green"] { color: green; }
        [data-color="orange"] { color: orange; }
        [data-color="purple"] { color: purple; }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.myHandler = function () {
            console.log('Click!');
        };

        window.getRandomNumber = function (max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
        }

        var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];
        window.changeHeadlineColor = function (croHeadline) {
            var random = getRandomNumber(5000);
            var randomString = random.toString();
            setTimeout(() => {
                var colorKey = (randomString.length < 4) ? 0 : parseInt(randomString.charAt(0));
                croHeadline.setAttribute('data-color', colors[colorKey]);
                changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
            }, random);
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        ////////////////////
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
        ////////////////////
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">OMG Click me!</div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', myHandler);

        setTimeout(() => {
            myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h1 id="cro-headline" data-color="red">Cro Metrics</h1>');
            var croHeadline = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
            changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
        }, getRandomNumber(5000));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But your code working without giving any error, I just test it.

Comment: Mind linking me to your test? Mine's still showing errors: https://codepen.io/marcwilk/pen/RwMWKmm

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.getElementById("myDiv")` is in the `head` tag which execute before the `DOM` loaded.

One solution is to add it in a `script` at the end of the body ( after the `DOM` loaded )

The second solution to make your script as module.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        [data-color="red"] { color: red; }
        [data-color="blue"] { color: blue; }
        [data-color="green"] { color: green; }
        [data-color="orange"] { color: orange; }
        [data-color="purple"] { color: purple; }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.myHandler = function () {
            console.log('Click!');
        };

        window.getRandomNumber = function (max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
        }

        var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];
        window.changeHeadlineColor = function (croHeadline) {
            var random = getRandomNumber(5000);
            var randomString = random.toString();
            setTimeout(() => {
                var colorKey = (randomString.length < 4) ? 0 : parseInt(randomString.charAt(0));
                croHeadline.setAttribute('data-color', colors[colorKey]);
                changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
            }, random);
        };
    </script>
     <script type="module">
      window.blah = function () {
        console.log('Click!');
      };
      document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', blah);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">OMG Click me!</div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('click', myHandler);

        setTimeout(() => {
            myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h1 id="cro-headline" data-color="red">Cro Metrics</h1>');
            var croHeadline = document.querySelector('#cro-headline');
            changeHeadlineColor(croHeadline);
        }, getRandomNumber(5000));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So the question specifically asks to write in the "YOUR CODE HERE" section to add a new click handler to the #myDiv element. Is there a way to manipulate the click handler so it fires after the DOM content has loaded?

Comment: I think I got it. Wrapping my original answer in: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {  });

Comment: Or you can make the `<script type="module"></script> which also makes it load after the page is parsed, I just update the answer.